# Google Ads Api: Get 'Actual cost per click'

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Is it possible to get `actual-cost-per-click` using google ads api V8?
I'm using the `click_view` report.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not possible atm. Please, check the link below to see the response from google-ads-api team:
https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/OOmbXfPbbGk